# Getting an exception while building an app using "mvn clean install"

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, build, jenkins-pipeline

**"Ant BuildException has occured: /api.previous.version doesn't exist " during mvn clean install**

I'm trying to build an app in Jenkins and it got failed with the exception:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (get-previous-api-version) on project scip: An Ant BuildException has occured: /buildservices/azure/workspace/xyz/target/api.previous.version doesn't exist
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<loadfile property="api.previous.version" srcFile="//target/api.previous.version"/>... @ 5:126 in /buildservices/azure/workspace/target/antrun/build-main.xml
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Maven Version : 3.6.3

Command : `mvn clean install -Dlicense.skipAddThirdParty=true -DskipTests`

Comment: /buildservices/azure/workspace/xyz/target/api.previous.version doesn't exist so ... have you checked that path?

Comment: I think target content of target folder gets deleted and created again with the jars evry time when build happens. @Stultuske

Answer (score 0):

based on the exception, it seems that you are faced with 2 issues.

1. Ant cannot find the maven version that you are using which is 3.6.3 and it's looking for the 1.8 version. Try specifying the version that in your `pom.xml` and see.
2. It cannot find the correct path in your azure workspace.

Another thing you could try would be to run `mvn clean install -e` without any specifiers other and see what are the results. I realised that going through the logs can be an indicator where it breaks.

I might be wrong, but this is what I can identify from the error. Let me know how it goes.